# Problemas ao iniciar o MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Estou iniciando os estudos em mongodb no ubuntu 18.04. Instalei ele, criei a pasta dbpath, mas ao iniciar com o comando `mongo` aparece esa mensagem de erro, como posso corrigir?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

fiz o `mongod` e depois `mongo` e deu o mesmo erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Pelo resultado parece que o servidor não está no ar.

Antes de executar o comando "mongo" tem de se executar o comando para iniciar o servidor "mongod"